# MSSQL SERVER 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I am trying to LINK MySQL and MSSQL but somehow stucks in this executing screen. The link server appears under the List Serves tab though. But when i try to run a query it stucks also on executing.

I follow the steps here in this link.
https://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/

[image]

Comment: hi any error message ...

Comment: None. It just stucks in the executing screen and i had to end mssql process using task manager just to stop it. Any suggestion to fix this? TIA

Comment: till we do not get error we cannot debug ...  just try to run simple query like SELECT CURDATE() and check is u get responce..

Comment: When i try to run this query 
SELECT * FROM MYSQL.theatrical.dbo.tblTrnBooking
It just shows "Executing query" in the bottom of my screen and never ends.

Comment: use query with limit 10 recored

Comment: Still it stucks on "Executing query" status :(

Comment: it means ur link server id not correctly mapped ...

Comment: How can i fix that?

Comment: with out  error or screen it is impossible to identify what is issue ..